# Accessing object value from nested objects in mongodb with php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

trying to get the value of candidate_id and count how many votes has been voted for a candidate
how do I access the candidate_id in php and count  it
MongoDB Structure

```
{
"_id":
{
"$oid":"637a7e16e490c4baadd9437f"
},
"civilid":"12769219",
"Blocks":
{
"BaseBlock":
{
"nonce":{"$numberInt":"0"},
"index":{"$numberInt":"0"},
"timestamp":"11-20-2022 22:39:30.082200",
"candidate_id":"0","previousHash":"0",
"hash":"d19f8d1d4bba2c22a82c1f3691f364fac86e992075bbd6a6ad239188d7a242e7"
},
"FirstBlock":
{
"nonce":{"$numberInt":"107675"},
"index":{"$numberInt":"1"},
"timestamp":"11-20-2022 22:39:30.082300",
"candidate_id":"103",
"previousHash":"d19f8d1d4bba2c22a82c1f3691f364fac86e992075bbd6a6ad239188d7a242e7",
"hash":"0000ac30bf8b97a9525d64a10a990ccf2b1fe4ee0c7c91fe665e572f0a39e11f"},
"SeconedBlock":
{
"nonce":{"$numberInt":"124478"},
"index":{"$numberInt":"2"},
"timestamp":"11-20-2022 22:39:30.082300",
"candidate_id":"103",
"previousHash":"0000ac30bf8b97a9525d64a10a990ccf2b1fe4ee0c7c91fe665e572f0a39e11f",
"hash":"0000a709f4faf36466cbd37ec34e09b64db309e306d238b586d4a6ae669f28da"
}}}
```

the display area in votes in int

[image]

I tried searching the web and reading the documents with no luck as I am new in MongoDB and PHP

Edit1:shared my code to get from db

```
$con = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>.ivtq9gb.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
$db = $con->VoterDatabase;
$collection3 = $db->Votes;
$cursor3 = $collection3->find(["Blocks"=>"FirstBlock"]);
$result = $cursor3->toArray();
foreach ($result as $row) 
{
$block[] = $row["candidate_id"];
}
var_dump($cursor3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the mongoDb drivers for PHP installed and are able to query the database. That's a prerequisite. Use the right driver and php version combination else it will fail (without errors sometimes)

Assuming the basic is set up, just convert the find to an array :-) That's the lazy and quick way to do it

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client($mongoUrl, [], $mongoOptions);
$db = $client->$mongoDb;
$coll = $db->$Ucollection;
$allUsersArray = $coll->find($find_array)->toArray();
$allUsersArrayFlat = json_decode(json_encode($allUsersArray), true);
```

The $find_array is a classic PHP array with AND, OR, etc. as criteria

```
$find_array = array(  '$and' => array( array('userName'=> $_POST['userName']), ));
```

Good luck!

Comment: yes I have the drivers and everything is working but the problem is how do I access the candidate_id object from the database and save it to array

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the code you have so far, to query the db and what is the result you are getting? Do remember to remove any sensitive data (server name, password, etc)

Comment: See Edit1,and ther result is bunch of information about the name of db and what query i wrote nothing related to my search

Comment: well... it is an array in $result. What is the issue? See var_dump of $row in your foreach or see var_dump of $block after the foreach. & then use that as you have already converted your find result to an array!